# mongod file got deleted by mistake in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, service, recover

By mistake i deleted the mongod file present in /usr/bin/ . I'm now unable to run the mongo command. I tried reinstalling mongodb, but mongod file is still absent. How can I get it back? Couldn't find suitable answers anywhere.

Comment: Recover from backup!?

Comment: completely remove mongodb and then try reinstall mongodb

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I didnt have a backup setup. But testdisk helped. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @TwinklePatel Yah i recovered the file and then reinstalled mongodb. Luckily it worked out. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recovered my lost file using testdisk, and reinstalled mongodb. It worked. I dont know if the recovery was required or not, but reinstalling mongodb hadnt worked for me earlier.